# How to set a smooth transition for nearly the same images?

Tags: jquery, transition, cycle, jquery-cycle

I have a series of 3 images I trow into an unordered list. The images are nearly the same and only a small piece of the image is changing. This way I get a 'movie' kinda effect.

I use the [jquery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

I run into the problem I can't seem to figure out how to set the transition to be so smooth the images blend into another. Now one image fades out and the other fades in... and this results in a flash between the images...

Can anyone share an example of a smooth blending of nearly the same images?

Comment: What effect are you using now ? `Fade` is about the best of the effects available for your needs ....

Comment: $('#yourImages').cycle() should just do that! See the third example http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Comment: When you look at that, you'll notice it's not completely 'blending' into the next image. And that's exactly my problem. BTW: I use `fade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I've modified the transition to barely noticably fading out so that it should look like each slide only fades in.  You may need to change the speed, delay, and/or timeout properties to match what you are *exactly* trying to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/12/

Transition:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.smooth = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    $slides.not(':eq(' + opts.currSlide + ')').css('opacity', .99);
    opts.before.push(function(curr, next, opts) {
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr, next, opts);
        opts.cssBefore.opacity = 0;
    });
    opts.animIn = {
        opacity: 1
    };
    opts.animOut = {
        opacity: .99
    };
    opts.cssBefore = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    };
};
```

Original:

The closest you can get to a super smooth transition is like this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({fx:'fade', continuous:1, timeout:0, easeIn: 'linear', easeOut: 'linear'});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/6/

This also works great with horizontal/vertical fx's.

Round 2:

I've updated the jsfiddle to a new custom fx called smooth:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/12/

You may need to play around with the speed:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.smooth = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
    $slides.not(':eq(' + opts.currSlide + ')').css('opacity', .99);
    opts.before.push(function(curr, next, opts) {
        $.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr, next, opts);
        opts.cssBefore.opacity = 0;
    });
    opts.animIn = {
        opacity: 1
    };
    opts.animOut = {
        opacity: .99
    };
    opts.cssBefore = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    };
};


$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'smooth',
    continuous: 1,
    speed: 300,
    easeIn: 'linear',
    easeOut: 'linear'
});​
```

Comment: Superb! This works perfectly (though when looking at the demo I thought it wouldn't - there the background still doesn't stay black and 'flickering' occurs).

Comment: I think if your images are similar and smaller it would be a little smoother.

Comment: Actually they are bigger, but yes more similar. Thanks though, works like a charm!

Comment: I don't know why... but I think I had some caching issues. It doesn't work at all where it comes to blending the image. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @hphoeksma I've updated the answer by building a new transition based on the orignal fade.  See if it works for you.

Comment: For some reason the moderators say my edit doesn't answer the question so I'm stumped since they didn't ask it.  Anyways, I've updated this jsfiddle by building a new fx.  See if it addresses it. http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/tcRCj/12/

Comment: @hphoeksma That looks great.  I have no idea why 2 moderators rejected my 1st edit telling me that it didn't resolve your issue.  That plugin is very versatile and was a learning experience for me to get it to work for you.

Comment: Well, you definitely helped me out here :-) Thanks again! Glad to hear you got something out of it too!